VNC Server for Gateway with 100 users. Giving each one a port is not an option
Currently we have a server to host remote VNC to provide remote linux desktops to our users. There are 100 users of whom 10 might be running a server at the same time.
This is fine on RHEL 7.0 as you can just start vncserver at the command line and it works.
However, we will soon need to assign a port and display to each individual user. This is impractical for us given the number of users.
Are there workarounds to  provide VNC to a unix desktop for our users after we are forced to upgrade our gateway servers?
All I find are instructions on how to set up vnc with a port and display assigned to each user.
Thanks for the help.

Why use VNC? Why not look into a product made for this, such as NoMachine

Nomachine is more efficient than vnc in both user expirience and bandwidth, and is neatly tunneled over SSH, meaning that it's easy to secure, and also doesn't need one port per user.

It's not really clear how you are currently using VNC. It kinda sounds like you are trying to use the (default) ad-hoc connection mechanism to match a (new) incoming connection to an already running session. Or are you trying to provide a mechanism for the user to choose which host they connect to? Is the "gateway" host something in between the client and the host where VNC is running or just a misleading name for the host where VNC is running? Do you the users to be able to choose which host they connect to, or are you looking for a VDI like solution?
VNC will happily run in multi-user mode - i.e. supporting lots of users on the same (server) port. Several display managers support this out of the box. I use lightdm.
If you need sessions to persist between connections that may be possible but not something I've looked at with VNC - its built in to xrdp if you're not tied to VNC as your protocol.
If the "gateway" is a proxy then there are lots of ways to mutliplex connections to servers sitting behind it - socks, ssh tunnels, port knocking, static client based maps, novnc.... but I'd be wondering why you are not simply using a VPN.
Or just use X. WSL can provide an X server, so does MobaXterm. Its possible to provision a X server on MS-Windows with strictly open source software but the last time I did this, the process was rather involved.

Thanks.
So we have a few gateway machines that users log into to then log into a number of other production machines. This is done so that those machines don't have to run vnc for them as they are doing other jobs.
What we do now is a user logs into a gateway machine. Starts a vncserver then connects a vnc viewer session to that (Using ssh tunnelling) and away they go. This works nicely. We are told this is going away and we are looking for a replacement for this process. We can't give every user a port no to connect to because that would become unwieldy. So looking at what we should do.

What they do AFTER they are connected via VNC is completely irrelevant to your question (other than creating confusion about how things are described). Why not just use the reverse connection in VNC? "We are told this is going away" - so there are external requirements driving a change which you've not told us about. Don't you think you might get more useful answers if you told us what those requirements are?

"Gateway" in this context is what others probably refer to as "jump host".

....no, I think OP is trying to tell us that the VNC server is running on the box described as the gateway.

Thanks not sure what a reverse vnc connection is but I will look.
To clarify what we want is for our users on the Windows network to be able to start up a vnc connection to run a Linux Desktop so they can access our linux network. What we have now works fine. Log into a machine, run vncserver then connect to that from Windows.
Sadly every installation of vncserver we have tells us that the ability to start vncserver from the command line will be deprecated soon and you will need to assign a port to each user. We have too many users to give them a dedicate port each.

My Question is what is the recommended replacement for our usage case.
Thanks and sorry for not communicating well.

AFAIK, what you want isn't possible with just a typical VNC server itself. (By typical I mean like free software like TigerVNC or so. Not sure about non-free solutions.)
From what I could understand, it seems that what you want is some kind of server that works like an SSH server, which "demuxes" incoming connections with a "listening process" and "wires" each of them to a "worker process" spawned (which would in turn spawns a shell instance).
However, VNC server implementations I've seen cannot be configured to work in a similar "fashion". Often they would either accept only one connection at a time, or "at best", they would wire multiple connections to the same X client/server. (X client here refers to the "screen capturing" part of the VNC server.)
With that said, I did see in Xvnc(1) (of TigerVNC) that it supports a special mode that leverages standard input/output (instead of listening on a TCP port itself) so that it can be used with e.g. an inetd implementation, which seems to offer similar "demuxing functionality" mentioned above (i.e., it will spawn a new Xvnc instance for each connection and wire the connection to that instance). Each instance will then spawns some sort of display/login manager/screen that allows a user to login and start a graphical session. The caveat would be, if the connection is closed for whatever reason, everything spawned inside the session would die. In other words, you can't "detach from" and "reattach to" a session. Also I have no actual experience with such setup. I'm merely sharing what I've read. (And inetd, regardless of which implementation, seems to be considered archaic these days...)

Maybe you should accept, desktop cann`t be used by more people at the same time, even if it consumes a lot of momory.
This is a simple script, to show you how to create new process for new user in vncserver
sudo useradd $usersname
echo $password | sudo passwd --stdin $usersname

sudo /bin/cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@:${username}.service
sudo sed -i "s/<USER>/${username}/g" /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@:${username}.service
sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:${username}

one user have one password, and vnc password just set up in jump server

Thanks for the reply it is much appreciated.
The machines work fine and usually have only up to 10 users which works nicely. (They are just gate way machines to the rest of the network.) The issue is with giving all of our hundreds of users an individual port numbers if add hoc vncserver calls go away.
Our current process is user on a Windows machine connects to the gateway machine starts a vncserver then connects using vnc viewer.
Can you explain what the process above does? It creates users which is not the issue. We have lots of users and are looking at how to manage the vnc access.

So your question is "you not want to have hundreds of processes running on the server at the same time, and only start the process when it is needed"?
If so, the problem is complicated, maybe you need an ansible to remotely start the process
